# Is there a way to use opensuse 11.2 's greenish theme in another distro?

Tags: themes, opensuse-11.2

I am currently using Arch+kdemod with the default Air theme. But I like opensuse's greenish theme very much. Is there a way to import opensuse's theme into my current environment?

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot? I'm pretty sure OpenSuSe's theme **is** Air.

Comment: Your half right, John T

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Opensuse 11.2 uses the Air theme, packaged  and renamed called opensuse Air.
the greenish tint, is given to it by the background, also called opensuse air.

For anything else, use the KDE air theme and just move that background from suse (or find it on google or kde-look.org) and use it there. when its setup as the background, the taskbar will be tinted green.

Comment: Thanks. set up the wallpaper. Although the task bar is still different(opensuse's is not transparent), it's close.

Comment: i'm sure you could find it somewhere, but i'm pretty sure its the exact same thing.